# Add Linux EFI (like grub) as Windows boot entry

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

I primarily use Windows for everything, but for coding I want to use a dual booted Linux OS. If I keep using grub as the default bootloader, then the startup time for Windows is drastically affected. It takes too long to boot Windows, and after a feature update I always have to reconfigure the EFI boot menu using EasyUEFI.

I don't want to launch grub while booting and select the "Windows" option to boot Windows.

I want to launch the Windows bootloader showing a list of installed operating systems, like other versions of Windows and Linux grub too. This way Windows will boot up way faster and a simple feature update does not affect the Windows boot menu.

Windows boot menu:

[image]

Comment: You need to learn how to use UEFI settings > Boot menu (or the one-time boot menu / boot override) if you don't want to use Grub. The solution in the answer below is very likely to produce the exact same results as a proper Grub if not worse. That said I really don't believe *"the startup time for Windows is drastically affected"* because I've installed thousands of dual-boots and didn't notice ANY difference other than the inevitable added time for the Grub menu selection.

Comment: @ChanganAuto perhaps the OP compares a startup from grub with the startup time after a Windows 10 "shutdown", which isn't really a shutdown but a hibenate or sleep.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille It's a possibility indeed but then the OP *should* know that disabling Fast Startup in Windows is a *must* no matter the scenario. And even as "normal" I've extensively tested booting Windows directly and via Grub and found no difference other than what's inherent of using an additional chainloaded step (Grub), i.e. from the point of selecting Windows in Grub or directly booted NO measurable difference whatsoever.

Comment: @ChanganAuto actually there is a difference in boot time. When you turn on the PC, it boots up to grub. And when you select Windows, it literally restarts the system with the Windows bootloader selected. This is the place that slows down boot time. If it is a Windows bootloader, it would straight up bring to lock screen without even rebooting another time, and have Linux as an option.

Comment: No, it absolutely NOT restarts the system.

Comment: *poorly photoshopped screenshot that I want for reference* -> The photoshopping isn't bad but it doesn't match the reality. The Windows bootloader can only boot other Windows. This being what you want it settles the question: No, it can't be done. Now read again the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Grub2Win. If not you can try that.

- Boot into Windows.
- Download and Install Grub2Win from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/).
- Add entry of your Operating System.
- Then restart.

You would be greeted with grub first select windows, then you would see options to boot to windows or grub 2 win select grub 2 win if you would like to boot to linux or select windows.

Then you could remove grub if you like.

Comment: Well, you couldn't understand my context. For better understanding, I have posted a screenshot. I want to load Windows Boot Manager by default and it should boot Windows without restarting. It's okay to restart for Linux boot.

Comment: There's no context, what you want is impossible.

Comment: Grub2Win boots into windows boot manager instead of grub bootloader and asks whether if you want to boot into windows or Grub2Win which lets you boot into linux. Just delete the grub bootloader after setting up Grub2Win.

Comment: I just tried grub2win on a system with UEFI.  It actually replaces the default windows EFI loader.   On top of that, it requires secure boot to be disabled.  So probably not the solution people are looking for to dual boot Windows and Linux (i.e., one might just as well use grub that was installed by Linux.)  I guess it is useful to people who wants to have GRUB without having to install Linux?

Comment: I get "Virus detected" by MS Antimalware when I download grub2win.