# Is there a command line way to boot into UEFI firmware?

Tags: windows, boot, uefi

I currently have a mini PC with a dead CMOS battery. Its got a built in/emmc install of windows 10, and a Proxmox install on a separate SSD. It'll boot into windows by default (even when I want it going into proxmox), and its kind of annoying to reboot, remember/hit  the boot select or UEFI screen fast enough and pick an OS.

I can't remove the windows drive. Its soldered in.

On *another* system that runs linux, there's a [command line way to boot into the UEFI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318143/reboot-the-system-into-uefi-settings/318146#318146)

Is there an equivilent powershell or cmd builtin or other way to boot into UEFI from windows without going through the shift/restart dance?

Comment: Try `shutdown /r /fw` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown

Comment: @Gantendo I think Journeyman Geek is testing us ;-) ?. I think this is the best way. Great comment (answer!), though you should have entered it as an answer.

Comment: With the small addition that it needs to be run as admin, it works. As for 'testing' - its not really documented here, and we are trying to build a knowledgebase. This is both 'low hanging fruit' and surprisngly hard to find. @Gantendo you might want to post this as an answer ;)

Comment: Can you replace Windows on the soldered drive with Linux and configure GRUB so that it boots the other drive?

Comment: I don't really want to - I'd like the option of getting it as stock as possible should someone else need it, and I *should* change the battery soonish which would solve the underlying issue

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1699037/add-linux-efi-like-grub-as-windows-boot-entry

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`shutdown /r /fw` (requires elevation)

https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown